# how to get data from prototype cell to controller and update model from it in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

i have a table view which has 2 prototype cell, one of it has textview in it which shows the data in the model, but the textview is editable so the user can edit the text it is showing. i want to store the edited text back to model through controller i couldn't find any way to get data from prototype cell back to controller to update my model

//code for viewcontroller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myC = MyModelHolder()

var numberOfCell = -1{
    didSet{
        print(numberOfCell)
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!{
    didSet{
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

@IBAction func textAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    numberOfCell += 1
    myC.createEmpty()
   }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of arrays \(myC.myArr.count)")
        return myC.myArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch myC.myArr[indexPath.row].identifier {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as? TextCell
            cell?.textArea.text = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str

            return cell!
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imgCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCell
            let url = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].img
            print("cell url")
            print(url!)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            cell?.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            return cell!
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "error has occur please check the code"
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

// code for prototype table cell

```
import UIKit

class TextCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textArea: UITextView!{
        didSet{
            textArea.delegate = self
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create closure variable inside `TextCell` class which gets called once you need to save something

```
class TextCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    var textSaved: ( (String) -> Void )? // call it with `textSaved?("someTextFromTextView")`
}
```

... for example you can call it inside implemented `UITextViewDelegate` delegate method `textViewDidEndEditing` which handle moment which we need

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textSaved?(textView.text)
}
```

Then inside `cellForRowAt` assign cell's `textSaved` and declare what will happen after `textSaved` will be called from cell ... you need to change `str` of certain item

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as! TextCell
cell.textArea.text = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str

cell.textSaved = { text in
    self.myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str = text
}

return cell
```

Comment: But make sure to break retain cycle in `cell.textSaved = { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Use protocol Approach in Your cell

Something like

```
 protocol TextCellDelegate: class {
    func didChangeText(text: String)
}
```

And in your cell you can have a var for delegate like

```
 weak var delegate: TextCellDelegate?
```

Also your cell should have the textview delegate method

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    // Do the logic you want to happen everytime the textView changes
    // So we call the delegate method from here

self.delegate?.didChangeText(textView.text!)

}
```

Now in your VC you just need to implement these custom delegate replacing

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as? TextCell
            cell?.textArea.text = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str

            return cell!
```

with

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as? TextCell
            cell?.textArea.text = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str
cell.delegate = self;

        return cell!
```

and add

```
extension ViewController: TextCellDelegate{

    func didChangeText( text : String) {
        //Update the model Here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10.1:**

Another way to get the text is set a tag for your textFiled/s. And using textField delegate methods capture the entered text or validate them while the users are typing.

**For Example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textCell", for: indexPath) as? TextCell

    //You can have as many textFiled in your cell. give each a unique tag number.
    cell.textArea.delegate = self
    cell.textArea.tag = 22

    cell?.textArea.text = myC.myArr[indexPath.row].str
}
```

If you have many textFields. create an enum for their tags:

```
enum TextFieldTags:Int {
case textArea = 22, textArea1, textArea2
}
```

Add `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to your viewController. And Implement its methods those you need.

```
//textField Did End Editing
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if let textFieldTag: TextFieldTags = TextFieldTags(rawValue: textField.tag) {

        switch textFieldTag {

        case .textArea:
              print(textField.text)
        case .textArea1:
              print(textField.text)
        case .textArea2:
              print(textField.text)
        }
    }
}
```